# How do you authenticate a SSIS web call?

Tags: c#, soap, ssis

I am writing a SOAP web method (in C#) that is to be called from SSIS HTTP Connection Manager. I need to extract the username and password from the web request. I thought they would be in the header, but they're not.

Has anyone done this?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: You are probably using Default Credentials (Trusted_Connection=True) which uses Windows credentials.  SQL server can either use SQL credentials or windows credentials.  So you usually will set up a windows group account for the database.  Then set SQL server to use the windows group account.  Then Group Account must be installed on all PCs accessing the database.  Then put Users into group account that need to access database.  The authentication is then done by windows like when you remote access files on a Network on a remote PC (or file server).

Comment: Let me explain further.  When you open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) a login window pops up the has the user account and password.  You normally press OK because the login user defaults are added to the form.  So your connection Manager will already have trusted credentials.  So you can get username from process (not password) : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aeff7e41-a4ba-4bf0-8677-81162040984d/retrieving-username-of-a-running-process?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: I'm fairly sure I'm not using windows credentials. In SSIS, I've created a Web Service Task. In the task, using the HTTP Connection Manager Editor dialog, I've set the server URL to my SOAP web service, checked Use credentials and entered a username and password. When the web service task is executed, my SOAP web service is called. I just don't know who called me :/